# mysql jdbc connectivity error in eclipse juno plugin project

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I am using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` for database connectivity from a view. 
The JDBC connectivity code has been used in 3 JSP-struts2 projects in eclipse Helios and works fine there. 
Here it is throwing

```
***No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentinfo***.

***!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-08-10 14:45:22.635
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.iiitb.studentinfo.CaptureDetails.LoadToDatabase(CaptureDetails.java:50)*** and stack trace goes on.
```

Any clue why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` file into *Build Path* or copy it to `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: I have created a /libs folder and added mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar to it. then have added this location in to build path. I have already done it. thats not the issue. The Connection code is working properly for helios jsp project.     PS:JDK version is 1.7